# How to place XY drawings on a page?

Tags: xy-pic

I need to use this `\usepackage[all]{xy}` and i need to know how can i place the drawing i made lets say to the upper-left corner. How do i do that?

```
\begin{displaymath}
    \xymatrix{A & B \\
              C & D }
\end{displaymath}
```

What should be added to that code?

Comment: I don't think there was any need to ask the same question again. You can edit your posts (there is an *edit* link right below the tags), so editing your first question would have been better.

Comment: It wasn't being commented, that's why i asked. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it on the upper-left corner of text area, just use

```
\begin{document}%
\noindent\(\xymatrix{A & B \\
              C & D }
\)
\end{document}
```

If you want the first line os square in the almost left middle, use

```
\begin{document}
\
\vfil
\noindent
\rule{1cm}{.4pt} % just to show baseline
\(\xymatrix{A & B \\
              C & D }
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about left middle corner